# For loop Error with write.csv function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm a R novice trying to write his first script. I have encountered a problem within a for loop.
In my code I am creating 2 column data frames from 2 vectors sharing a partially common name. I use a for loop to perform this for several of these common names (defined by vector a).

```
paste("A",1:4,sep="")->a    
for ( i in a) {
  j<-grep(x= ls(pos=1), pattern=i, value=TRUE)
  data.frame(do.call(cbind,mget(j)))-> k
  print(k)
}
```

This works, but I encounter a problem, when I want to print these data frames as separate csv files using this code:

```
for ( i in a) {
  j<-grep(x= ls(pos=1), pattern=i, value=TRUE)
  data.frame(do.call(cbind,mget(j)))-> k
  print(k)
  write.table (k, file = paste("Results_",i, sep=''))
}
```

The error displayed reads as follows

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
 invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Additionally, the fllwing has worked, but, of course, only creating one csv file of the last iteration

```
for ( i in a) {
j<-grep(x= ls(pos=1), pattern=i, value=TRUE)
data.frame(do.call(cbind,mget(j)))-> ff
print(ff)
write.table (ff, file = "results_df.csv")}
```

Thanks!

Comment: also: In some other questions regarding this error, it was mentioned that I need the permission to write. I do, as write.csv has worked previously in the same directory

Comment: Nothing good can come from altering the value of the index variable you are using for the `for` loop. (That's a hint.)

Comment: ...also, if you're really just starting, be aware that (1) `data.frame(cbind())` is generally a pretty bad idea; `cbind` will coerce all objects to one type, so it can be a very misleading and error prone way to create a data.frame, and (2) Try to avoid bad habits early, like the bad habit of keeping single, isolated, but similarly named objects in your workspace. If they are related, and need to be computed on in groups, put them in a named list. If you're just beginning and you're resorting to `get` or `mget` you've probably not chosen the best path.

Comment: Thank You @joran I will keep this in mind! What I have tried before is creating two list of data frames. But from the lists I would need to cbind always the [1] with [1], [2] with [2] etc... here, i just couldn't find a solution

Comment: @joran I changed the code to conserve the index variable, (see edit). But this didn't fix the problem

Comment: If you have two lists of dataframes, `Map(cbind, list_1, list_2)` will give you a list of `cbind(list_1[[1]], list_2[[1]]), cbind(list_1[[2]], list_2[[2]])`, etc.  Also, right-assignment with `->` if often discouraged against. It's uncommon and usually catches people by surprise.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks! Using this function solved my problem by cbind dataframes from two lists into one. Then I was able to write.csv of these dataframes. Would     mapply  also work for this function?

Comment: Yes probably. Please let this be a lesson to ask the real question - or at least present the context of your problem. Otherwise we'd still be debugging an unnecessary for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the file error is:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :   invalid
>   'description' argument In addition: Warning message: In if (file ==
>   "") file <- stdout() else if (**is.character(file)**) { :   **the condition**
>   **has length > 1** and only the first element will be used

'file' is apparently a vector and not a single string.

This may not be the only problem.